# How do I get all specific items from my json such as everyones "erecno"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

```
[
   {
      "userData":{
         "mail id":"mawdawd@sigmatelecom.com",
         "erecno":"373242000101029",
         "last name":"wadD",
         "first name":"wadwa",
         "id":"1000"
      },
      "totalDeduction":7,
      "lateDays":0,
      "cutSodexoDetails":{
         "2021-08-10":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-10",
         "2021-08-02":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-02",
         "2021-08-04":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-04",
         "2021-08-03":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-03",
         "2021-08-06":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-06",
         "2021-08-05":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-05",
         "2021-08-09":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-09"
      }
   },
   {
      "userData":{
         "mail id":"massimo.td@sigmatelecom.com",
         "erecno":"371050000000110067",
         "last name":"POYRAZ",
         "first name":"Massimo",
         "id":"1001"
      },
      "totalDeduction":7,
      "lateDays":1,
      "cutSodexoDetails":{
         "2021-08-10":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-10",
         "2021-08-02":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-02",
         "2021-08-03":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-03",
         "2021-08-06":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-06",
         "2021-08-05":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-05",
         "2021-08-09":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-09"
      }
   },
   {
      "userData":{
         "mail id":"uaafwf@cellsigma.com",
         "erecno":"3432420000110097",
         "last name":"fwfwffawafwaACI",
         "first name":"Unsadasdal",
         "id":"1006"
      },
      "totalDeduction":1,
      "lateDays":0,
      "cutSodexoDetails":{
         "2021-08-03":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-03"
      }
   }
]
```

This is my finalData.json. I'd like to get all of the erecno's but with my code I only get the first erecno. How do I get all?

```
 const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync("finalData.json");
    const dataJSON = dataBuffer.toString();
    const a = JSON.parse(dataJSON);

    for (let key in a) {
        if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const test = a[key].userData.erecno;
            return res.status(200).send({result: test});
            // returns the first erecno
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you return in a `for` loop you actually exit out of the loop. You need to store the `erecno` in an array and send a response after the loop has finished.

Comment: You can initialize an array before the for loop, inside the if statement append to it, and afterwards return the array instead of a single result

Comment: @Reyno can you please code it for me I'm new to these and learning :')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const dataJSON = '[{"userData":{"mail id":"mawdawd@sigmatelecom.com","erecno":"373242000101029","last name":"wadD","first name":"wadwa","id":"1000"},"totalDeduction":7,"lateDays":0,"cutSodexoDetails":{"2021-08-10":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-10","2021-08-02":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-02","2021-08-04":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-04","2021-08-03":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-03","2021-08-06":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-06","2021-08-05":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-05","2021-08-09":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-09"}},{"userData":{"mail id":"massimo.td@sigmatelecom.com","erecno":"371050000000110067","last name":"POYRAZ","first name":"Massimo","id":"1001"},"totalDeduction":7,"lateDays":1,"cutSodexoDetails":{"2021-08-10":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-10","2021-08-02":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-02","2021-08-03":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-03","2021-08-06":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-06","2021-08-05":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-05","2021-08-09":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-09"}},{"userData":{"mail id":"uaafwf@cellsigma.com","erecno":"3432420000110097","last name":"fwfwffawafwaACI","first name":"Unsadasdal","id":"1006"},"totalDeduction":1,"lateDays":0,"cutSodexoDetails":{"2021-08-03":"Cut Sodexo Because Of Late On 2021-08-03"}}]';


// const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync("finalData.json");
// const dataJSON = dataBuffer.toString();

const a = JSON.parse(dataJSON);
let resultArray = [];

    for (let key in a) {
        if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const test = a[key].userData.erecno;
            resultArray.push(test);
        }
    }
    
// return res.status(200).send({result: resultArray});
console.log(resultArray);


// you could also use map()

console.log ('map result 1')
console.log(a.map(getErecno));

function getErecno(item) {
  return item.userData.erecno;
}

console.log ('map result 2')
console.log(a.map((item) => item.userData.erecno));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, I understand now. It gave all erecnos as I wanted

Comment: Great to hear could you make it the answer if it is, please.